# Why is table output appearing above instead of below concatenated sentence?

Tags: r, matrix

I have the code

```
cat("Misclassification table of predicted y versus true y:","\n",
  print(table(pred = pred.class, true = test$low))
```

And it gives the output

```
true
pred  0  1
   0 10  6
   1  1  2
Misclassification table of predicted y versus true y: 
 10 1 6 2
```

I am not sure why the table appears above the concatenated sentence?

The output should look like

```
Misclassification table of predicted y versus true y: 
true
pred  0  1
   0 10  6
   1  1  2
```

Comment: It seems like `print` messes it up. It also seems that `cat` can't handle such output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Hence the recommendation for a custom print method :-)

Comment: It's because print is having its side effect of displaying output as well as returning its value into cat. Is there any reason you can't separate the cat and the print, or even use two print statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you need to do often? If it is, I would suggest that you create a custom print method, as is done in the following example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- table(true = sample(0:1, 20, TRUE),
           pred = sample(0:1, 20, TRUE))
class(x) <- c("myClass", class(x))
print.myClass <- function(x, ...) {
   cat("Misclassification table of predicted y versus true y:","\n\n")
   print.table(x)
}
x
# Misclassification table of predicted y versus true y: 
# 
#     pred
# true 0 1
#    0 5 4
#    1 7 4
```

---

Otherwise, you can perhaps explore `capture.output`:

```
y <- unclass(x)
y
#     pred
# true 0 1
#    0 5 4
#    1 7 4

cat("blah blah blah\n", capture.output(y), sep = "\n")
# blah blah blah
# 
#     pred
# true 0 1
#    0 5 4
#    1 7 4
```